# Avoiding unnecessary memory consumption in Python and wxPython

Tags: python, python-2.7, memory, memory-management, wxpython

I am working with python v2.7 and wxPython v3.0 on Windows 7 OS. In my application I have a panel named as `myPanel`. I have a image as a background on `myPanel` the image names is `green.bmp` The `myPanel` contains a button named as `myButton`. This `myButton` also contains an image as a background named as `blue.bmp` The thread simply changes the image on `myButton`.

*For the demo purpose I am using the same image again and again on `myButton`. In my real world problem I have different images.*

**Problem**: After executing my application, when I see the memory consumption in the task manager I observed that the memory consumption keeps increasing. What is wrong with my code below that causes unnecessary memory consumption? How can I avoid this?

**Code**: The images used in the code can be downloaded from here [Green.bmp](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/62280363/green.bmp) and [Blue.bmp](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/62280363/blue.bmp). The code snippet is provided below:

```
import wx
from wx.lib.pubsub import setupkwargs
from wx.lib.pubsub import pub
from threading import Thread
import threading
import time

class gui(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, id, title):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, None, id, title, size=(500,400))
        myPanel = wx.Panel(self, -1, size=(300,200))
        image_file1 = 'green.bmp'
        image1 = wx.Image(image_file1, wx.BITMAP_TYPE_ANY).ConvertToBitmap()
        self.bitmap2 = wx.StaticBitmap(myPanel, -1, image1, (0, 0))
        pub.subscribe(self.addImage, 'Update')

    def addImage(self):
        myButton = wx.Button(self.bitmap2, -1, size =(30,30), pos=(20,20))
        image_file2 = 'blue.bmp'
        image2 = wx.Image(image_file2, wx.BITMAP_TYPE_ANY).ConvertToBitmap()
        self.bitmap1 = wx.StaticBitmap(myButton, -1, image2, (0, 0))

class myThread(Thread):
    def __init__(self):
        Thread.__init__(self)
        self.start()
    def run(self):
        while True:
            time.sleep(2)
            wx.CallAfter(pub.sendMessage, 'Update')

if __name__=='__main__':
    app = wx.App()
    frame = gui(parent=None, id=-1, title="Test")
    frame.Show()
    myThread()
    app.MainLoop()
```

Thanks for your time.

Comment: Since you have working code you may be better off at [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: what happens if you remove all but the first line in `addImage()`?

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian Then the memory consumption is stable and don't increases. This is what I want. But then there is no image on button too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is in addImage.  Each time this line executes:

```
myButton = wx.Button(self.bitmap2, -1, size =(30,30), pos=(20,20))
```

You are adding another child window to self.bitmap2.  The window perfectly overlaps the previous one added, so it is not apparent that you have multiple children.  To see what is happening, add this line to the bottom of addImage:

```
print len(self.bitmap2.GetChildren())
```

To fix this problem you should destroy all the children before you add the new button.  Add this to the top of addImage

```
self.bitmap2.DestroyChildren()
```

However, this approach destroys *ALL* windows you have added to bitmap2, so tread lightly.  If you want to only destroy the button, you should keep a reference to it.  I've modified your program to use this approach:

```
import wx
from wx.lib.pubsub import setupkwargs
from wx.lib.pubsub import pub
from threading import Thread
import threading
import time

class gui(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, id, title):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, None, id, title, size=(500,400))
        myPanel = wx.Panel(self, -1, size=(300,200))
        image1 = wx.Image('green.bmp', wx.BITMAP_TYPE_ANY).ConvertToBitmap()
        self.bitmap2 = wx.StaticBitmap(myPanel, -1, image1, (0, 0))
        pub.subscribe(self.addImage, 'Update')
        self.myButton = None

    def addImage(self):
        # Don't keep adding children to bitmap2
        if self.myButton:
            self.myButton.Destroy()
        self.myButton = wx.Button(self.bitmap2, -1, size =(30,30), pos=(20,20))
        image2 = wx.Image('blue.bmp', wx.BITMAP_TYPE_ANY).ConvertToBitmap()
        self.bitmap1 = wx.StaticBitmap(self.myButton, -1, image2, (0, 0))


class myThread(Thread):
    def __init__(self):
        Thread.__init__(self)
        self.start()
    def run(self):
        while True:
            time.sleep(2)
            wx.CallAfter(pub.sendMessage, 'Update')

if __name__=='__main__':
    app = wx.App()
    frame = gui(parent=None, id=-1, title="Test")
    frame.Show()
    myThread()
    app.MainLoop()
```

Comment: I thought to apply the same concept but I was missing this Destroy(). Thanks